# Does adding more drives to a RAID 10 Array increase performance?

Tags: raid, storage, storage-area-network

I'd like to know if I were to add additional drives to an existing Raid 10 if this would increase the speed of the entire array?

Comment: Related: [This question describing the architecture and benefits of the various RAID levels](http://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.
Generally this will increase the *potential* read and write capabilities of the system. Some of this depends on your application, though. Also, you want the array expansion to redistribute data across the additional disks in order to leverage the higher number of spindles.

Answer (score 7):

Try [this Raid performance calculator](http://www.wmarow.com/strcalc/) and you will get the answser :-)

And yes, it will normaly increase performance.

Comment: The link is dead. :-/